# How to create visualization from data inside a hit in kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am looking to create dashboard in kibana using the data from the postgresql database. But the datas are shown up in the same hit in kibana, so can't able to create the visualization.

I would like to create visualization in kibana from the data I had fetched from postgresql. I need to create visualization by comparing the datas inside single column in postgresql. But in kibana, the data in single column of postgresql is showing in the single hit of kibana. So, I am unable to create the visualization from this single hit data. If there is any way to filter the data inside a hit in kibana or to check the word count in single hit?

Comment: you need to provide example and what have you tried so far

Comment: I have used inner hits in dev tools to check the content in elastic search and it worked fine. But can't able to view the result in discover of kibana.
for example, I have failed word 100 times in a hit, need to create graph to check the count of word failed.

Comment: have you created index pattern for it?

Comment: I am sorry, just have only one index pattern and inside that all the data are there.

Comment: can you run /_search on your index and paste results, I don't quite get it what is the problem

Comment: "Dns": "", "Fat": "1.1.1.8 - Mounting of vfat filesystems is not Disabled      FAILED", "Ftp": "", "Gdm": "1.7.2 - GDM Login Banner is not configured     FAILED", "Hfs": "1.1.1.4 - Mounting of hfs filesystems is not Disabled     FAILED", "Mcs": "", "Nis": "", "Ntp": "2.2.1.2 - NTP is not configured      FAILED", "Rds": "3.5.3 RDS is not Disabled     FAILED", "Rsh": "", "Tmp": "1.1.2 - Separate partition not exists for /tmp      FAILED",
This is my kibana data and Just need to find the number of FAILED in these from kibana.

Answer (score 0):

To find the number of "FAILED" you need to use `match` query in `Kibana` like:

```
GET <YOUR_INDEX>/_count
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "<YOUR_FIELD>": "FAILED"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or if you have many fields:

```
GET <YOUR_INDEX>/_count
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":    "FAILED", 
      "fields": [ "<FIELD1>", "<FIELD2>" ] 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Dejan, thank you for your kindness and time. But the answer does not meet my requirement. I need to take the word count from a specific hit, that is the content I had gave above is from a single field of single hit. The query that you have gave above will only help to highlight the FAILED word only. ( I am sorry for the trouble, I tried to upload the screenshot, but I can't)